# adding dynamic field to form

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

My users can enter more than one address but I want an actual button that generates the extra fields as only one address is compulsory and empty fields will look ugly! I also need the extra addresses to go into mysql database.
How would I do with Javascript if PHP is not possible
Some code that may help:

```
<td width="732" valign="top"><p>
<h3 class="main">Address Details</h3>
<p class="normal"> You are able to add up to 3 addresses but only 1 is compulsory. 
However it would be helpful if you could insert 3 addresses:
<ul>
 <li>Permanent home address</li>
 <li>Postal address (where you will be from June to September)</li>
 <li>Local address (where you currently live)</li>
</ul>    
<?php   
 if(!empty($err))  {
   echo "<div class=\"msg\">";
  foreach ($err as $e) {
    echo "* $e <br>";
    }
  echo "</div>";    
   }
 ?>
 <br>
<form action="address.php" method="post" name="regForm" id="regForm" >
<table width="95%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="forms">
<tr> 
<td>Street<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span> 
</td>
<td><input name="Street"  type="text" id="Street" class="required" size="50"> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Line 2
</td>
<td><input name="Line2"  type="text" id="Line2" class="required" size="50"> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Line 3
</td>
<td><input name="Line3"  type="text" id="Line3" class="required" size="50"> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Town<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span> 
</td>
<td><input name="Town"  type="text" id="Town" class="required" size="30"> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Postcode<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span> 
</td>
<td><input name="Postcode"  type="text" id="Postcode" class="required" size="10"> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Country <font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td>
<td><select name="Country" class="required" id="select8">
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
           (etc)
          </select></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Telephone Number<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span> 
</td>
<td><input name="Tele"  type="text" id="Tele" class="required" > 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Fax<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span> 
</td>
<td><input name="Fax"  type="text" id="Fax" class="required" > 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Mobile<span class="required"><font color="#CC0000">*</font></span> 
</td>
<td><input name="Mobile"  type="text" id="Mobile" class="required" > 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td>Type <font color="#CC0000">*</font></span></td>
<td><select name="Type" class="required" id="select8">
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="H">Home</option>
            <option value="P">Postal</option>
            <option value="L">Local</option>


</table>
<p align="center">
<input name="doAddress" type="submit" id="doAddress" value="Submit">
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with Java? Did you mis-tag it with `Java` when you meant `Javascript`?

Comment: hello??? <tap, tap, tap> is this thing on?

Comment: yes sorry. Theres no need to be so rude  Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: Are you asking for help or for someone to do the coding for you?

Comment: any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show me where I was rude? where did I insult you? I was just trying to get your attention as you were ignoring our comments for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  First off, you need to drop the table format.  This is a very outdated and horrible practice to use for creating forms (not flexible).  You can create all this in css.

Seconds, css is your answer.  If you want the field to appear on a button click, then add a javascript event binding to remove a css class or css attribute where display=none.  Using a library like jQuery will make this very easy.

If you want the field to show based on a response from the server then when the submit is clicked you need to send an ajax request (again jQuery will make this very easy) and then updated the css class or display attribute on the successful callback method of the ajax request.